# How to perform delete api in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here is the url for the code for which delete operation is required
URL-http://something.com/Api/remove_player.php

These are the Parameters for request params - user_id, id
How to use delete API for these params?
This is the Interface class in which there is usage of @Path -

```
public interface ApiDeleteInterface {
    @DELETE("/Api/remove_player.php")
    Call<Response> getResponse(@Path("user_id") int user_id
    ,@Path("id") int id
    );
}
```

@DELETE annotation is used for detlete api. What shoul we use in response inside call?

Is this the correct way to make interface ?Should the code use path or any other annotation?

There is DELETE PLAYER API which has url and params below

```
URL - http://something.com/Api/remove_player.php
Parameters - user_id, id.
```

How to make delete API using retrofit?

Comment: did you read this? https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-delete-objects-on-the-server

Comment: @MadLeo I am unable to understand that can i use @path?

Answer (score 4):

Use `@Query` instead of `@Path` to set url parameters.

```
public interface ApiDeleteInterface {
    @DELETE("/Api/remove_player.php")
    Call<Response> getResponse(@Query("user_id") int user_id, @Query("id") int id);
}
```

The resulting url would look like: `/Api/remove_player.php?user_id=1&id=2`

`@Path` is a named replacement for a value in the URL. If you want to use `@Path`, your URL would need to update to something like:

```
public interface ApiDeleteInterface {
    @DELETE("/Api/user_id/{user_id}/id/{id}/remove_player.php")
    Call<Response> getResponse(@Path("user_id") int user_id, @Path("id") int id);
}
```

check out the docs

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html

Comment: how should I pass request params in  this  ApiDeleteInterface apiInterface = (ApiDeleteInterface) DeletePlayerClient.getApi();
Call<DeleteResponseModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse(ap.getIDKey(),Idview); What should i use in getresponse?

Comment: It looks like you are already passing the request params. The arguments of `getResponse()` will become your request parameters. That is, `ap.getIDKey()` and `Idview`

Comment: what should i write in  Call<DeleteResponseModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse(ap.getIDKey(),Idview);  Call<here>? Should i use my response model here.   In interface i need to use @FormUrlEncoded I think it's not working

Comment: Since the type parameter of the Call in your interface is `Call<Response>` you'd need to update it to: Call<Response> call = apiInterface.getResponse(ap.getIDKey(),Idview);  or change the return type of `getResponse` to `Call< DeleteResponseModel >`

Comment: will this work with @FormUrlEncoded annotation? Can I make this API without my response model? if yes then how

Comment: getting this exception     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST).